How to get the track name in Audacity scripting?
I am working with the Audacity mod-script-pipeline to write a script which goes through every clip of every track, and gets the name of each track.
My code works with everything, except getting the track name, but I can't figure out how to fetch this string using any of the scripting references in the documentation online.
My below code works for everything except getting the trackname, and I launch it with python3 script.py -a 3.
# python vin
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import requests
import json
import time
import re
import random
'''
Audacity mod-script-pipeline setup
'''
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    print("pipe-test.py, running on windows")
    TONAME = '\\\\.\\pipe\\ToSrvPipe'
    FROMNAME = '\\\\.\\pipe\\FromSrvPipe'
    EOL = '\r\n\0'
else:
    print("pipe-test.py, running on linux or mac")
    TONAME = '/tmp/audacity_script_pipe.to.' + str(os.getuid())
    FROMNAME = '/tmp/audacity_script_pipe.from.' + str(os.getuid())
    EOL = '\n'

print("Write to  \"" + TONAME +"\"")
if not os.path.exists(TONAME):
    print(" ..does not exist.  Ensure Audacity is running with mod-script-pipe.")
    sys.exit()

print("Read from \"" + FROMNAME +"\"")
if not os.path.exists(FROMNAME):
    print(" ..does not exist.  Ensure Audacity is running with mod-script-pipe.")
    sys.exit()

print("-- Both pipes exist.  Good.")

TOFILE = open(TONAME, 'w')
print("-- File to write to has been opened")
FROMFILE = open(FROMNAME, 'rt')
print("-- File to read from has now been opened too\r\n")

'''
Audacity Functions
'''
# Send a single command to audacity mod-script-pipeline
def send_command(command):
    #print("Send: >>> \n"+command)
    TOFILE.write(command + EOL)
    TOFILE.flush()

# Return the command response
def get_response():
    result = ''
    line = ''
    while line != '\n':
        result += line
        line = FROMFILE.readline()
    return result

# Send one command, and return the response
def do_command(command):
    send_command(command)
    response = get_response()
    #print("Rcvd: <<< \n" + response)
    return response

'''
#############################################
Start processing command line args
#############################################
'''

# auto -a "number of tracks"
if '-a' in sys.argv:
    numberOfTracksIndex = sys.argv.index('-a')
    numberOfTracks = int(sys.argv[numberOfTracksIndex+1])
    print(f"Export {numberOfTracks} tracks")


    # Unmute all tracks

    print("Go to first track")
    do_command('FirstTrack')
    time.sleep(1)

    trackCount = 0
    while(trackCount < numberOfTracks):
        print("\nMoves the cursor to the start of the selected track.")
        do_command('CursTrackStart')
        do_command('CursSelStart')
        time.sleep(1)

        print(f"Select track: {trackCount}")
        do_command(f'SelectTracks: Track={trackCount}')
        time.sleep(3)

###### Getting trackname here #######
        # Get trackname
        print("Get track name:")
        nameRsp = do_command('GetInfo: Type="Tracks"')
        print("name = ")
        print(nameRsp)
        trackName = "apple"

        # Select clips in this track
        maxClips = 3
        i = 1
        while i <= maxClips:
            print(f"select clip {i}")
            do_command('SelNextClip')

            time.sleep(2)
            print("export audio")

            i += 1

        trackCount += 1

This is the code that gets the track names:
###### Getting trackname here #######
        # Get trackname
        print("Get track name:")
        nameRsp = do_command('GetInfo: Type="Tracks"')
        print("name = ")
        print(nameRsp)
        trackName = "apple"

But my line do_command('GetInfo: Type="Tracks"') always returns an empty string.
How can I edit my Python code to get the track names such as my highlight "apple" text in this image?


just a guess... look for the word label in the document you linked

Didn't Audacity turn to the dark side?
